# Xcode changing iPhone Storyboard to universal Storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ipad

I created app on iPhone via Xcode and now I need to create it for an iPad as well. I changed layout to regular hight

[image]

But when I run app on iPad it shows navigation bar but whole content is blank. I tried to change this line:

```
targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch"
```

to this line:

```
targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch.iPad"
```

also I tried this tutorial https://irawd.wordpress.com/2014/10/21/xcode-6-separate-storyboard-for-ipad-and-iphone/ but it didn't work as well.

The iPhone Storyboard that I took was already made, then I copied it and changed it into iPad as that tutorial shows.

Thanks in advance!